# GKTurnBasedMatch: Unable to get GKLocalPlayerListener delegate methods called on saveCurrentTurn(withMatch .. )?

Tags: ios, push-notification, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm trying to save match data with the Game Centre default function. The following function works pretty fine and things got saved.

```
self.myMatch?.saveCurrentTurn(withMatch: dataToSend, completionHandler: { (e) in

        print(e ?? "No Error:")

 })
```

This method was introduced in IOS 6, and at that time they were sending push notifications to the opponent as like the `endTurnWithNextParticipant`, but now in the current IOS 10, if they have removed feature of sending push notifications, but there should any other way to detect `matchData` update on opponents side.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the newer way is to use the player listener to detect this kind of change in the match. I have created an [example project of a turn based GameKit game](https://bitbucket.org/tenseg/hellogamekitios) that you are welcome to use as a skeleton. The key function is found in the `ViewController.swift` file:

```
///    Activates the player's turn.
open func player(_ player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventFor match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) {
    print("***** player received turn event \(didBecomeActive ? "and became active for" : "for") match \(match.shortID)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if didBecomeActive {
        // This event activated the application. This means that the user
        // tapped on the notification banner and wants to see or play this
        // match now.
        print("***** attaching the model to this match")
        model?.match = match
    } else if model?.match?.matchID == match.matchID {
        // This is the match the user is currently playing,
        // laoding the game model below iwll update to show the latest state
        print("***** refreshing data for this match")
    } else if match.currentParticipant?.player?.playerID == model?.localPlayerID {
        // It became the player's turn in a different match,
        // prompt the player to switch to the new match
        print("***** ignoring player's turn in match \(match.shortID)")
        gameTextView.text.append("\n\nFYI, it is your turn in another match.")
        return
    } else {
        // Something has changed in another match,
        // but not sure what.
        print("***** ignoring new data for match \(match.shortID)")
        gameTextView.text.append("\n\nFYI, something has changed in another match.")
        return
    }

    print("***** loading match")
    GameModel.loadGameModel(match: match) { model, error in
        guard self.isNotError(error, during: "model loading") else { return }
        guard let model = model else {
            print("***** no model created")
            self.gameLabel.text = "Error setting up game"
            self.thereHasBeenAnError = true
            return
        }
        print("***** match load succeeded")
        self.model = model
        self.model?.checkForWin() { won, error in
            guard self.isNotError(error, during: "end match request") else { return }
            if won {
                self.gameLabel.text = "You won!"
                self.turnButton.isEnabled = false
                self.resignButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The references to the game `model` will make much more sense in the context of the whole example project, but to your question: notice the "refreshing data for this match" line? That is how you detect new incoming match data. You can do with it whatever you need.

Comment: Firstly, this was a far late and we had to submit our project within the time at that time. 
Now, it's just for learning purpose. 
Please pay attention to me, this code `func player(_ player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventFor match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) { ..  }` will only be triggered with ending the turn from opponent. I need to know, a way, when you are not ending your turn, just saving your data on GameCentre, but how could I be known to that new data?

Comment: @AasimKhan, as I stated in my comment above, I have a full working example for you. You are wrong about the `player()` function, it will get called for events other than the end of a game. In the full example you will find a function called [`sharepoke()`](https://bitbucket.org/tenseg/hellogamekitios/src/0f15b3dbdf2d0a13605679a57c1af384d915b83e/HelloGameKitiOS/GameModel.swift?at=master#GameModel.swift-439) which demonstrates how to share new data about a game with the other players without ending the turn.